# 2 dimensional array changing during serialisation

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, deserialization

I'm serialising and deserialising a large two dimensional array of objects.  Each object contains instructions to creating a `BufferedImage` - this is done to get around `BufferedImage` not being directly serializable itself.

The class being serialised is:

```
public final class MapTile extends TransientImage
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;
    private transient BufferedImage f;
    transient BufferedImage b;
    int along;
    int down;
    boolean flip = false;
    int rot = 0;

    public MapTile(World w, int a, int d)
    {
        // f = w.getMapTiles();
        along = a;
        down = d;
        assignImage();
    }

    public MapTile(World w, int a, int d, int r, boolean fl)
    {
        // f = w.getMapTiles();
        along = a;
        down = d;
        rot = r;
        flip = fl;
        assignImage();
    }

    public int getA()
    {
        return along;
    }

    public int getD()
    {
        return down;
    }

    @Override
    public void assignImage()
    {
        if (f == null)
        {
            f = World.mapTiles;
        }
        b = f.getSubimage(along, down, World.squareSize, World.squareSize);
        if (rot != 0)
        {
            b = SmallMap.rotateImage(b, rot);
        }
        if (flip)
        {
            b = SmallMap.flipImage(b);
        }
        super.setImage(b);
        f.flush();
        b.flush();
        f = null;
        b = null;
    }
}
```

which extends:

```
public abstract class TransientImage implements Serializable
{
    private transient BufferedImage image;

    public BufferedImage getImage()
    {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage i)
    {
        image = i;
    }

    public abstract void assignImage();

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        in.defaultReadObject();
        assignImage();
    }
}
```

This will ultimately be part of a map - usually it is created randomly but certain areas must be the same each time, hence serialising them and reading the array back in.  As I will never need to save the image during normal usage I am putting in the write code:

```
try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("verticalroad.necro"))) 
{
    //out.writeObject(mapArray);
    //}
    //catch (IOException e) {
//}
```

in the class that creates the map, the read code:

```
    try{
        FileInputStream door = new FileInputStream(new File(f.getPath()+ "//verticalroad.necro"));
        ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(door);
        homeTiles = (MapTile[][]) reader.readObject();
        }
    catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Thrown an error" + e.getMessage());
        }
```

in the initialising class and commenting in and out as needed.

However.  Each time I run the program the contents of the two dimensional array (`mapArray` in write, `homeTiles` in read) is different.  Not only different from the one I (thought) I wrote, but also different each time the program is opened.

As can be seen, I'm printing out the `toString` to `System.out` which reveals further oddities.  As its just a standard array, the `toString` isn't 100% helpful but it seems to cycle between several distinct values.  However, even when the `toStringg` gives the same value, the contents of the array as displayed are not the same.

An example of a `toString` is `hometiles:[[Lriseofthenecromancer.MapTile;@7681720a`  Looking at the documentation for `Array.toString` ([here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)) it seems to be badly formed, lacking a trailing ].  I'm not sure if this is a clue to the issue or if its simply that the array is very large (several thousand objects) and its an issue of display space (I'm using NetBeans).

Any insight as to why this is changing would be appreciated.  My working assumption is that its serializing the array but not the contents.  But I have no idea a) if that's the case and b)if it is, what to do about it.

EDIT:  Looking into this a bit further, it seems that instance variables aren't being set immediately.  Printing them out directly after the call to `setImage()` has them all at zero, printing them from the calling class has them where they should be.

Comment: Whoops, thanks for the typo catch there @Jim Garrison

Comment: You'll get much more attention if you take some care to properly format your code (correct indentation, remove tab characters) before posting it.

Comment: Where is your `toString()` for `MapTile`? Have you tried writing a `toString()` and seeing if the content has actually changed?

Comment: Sorry, not certain I understand you.  Do you mean have I tried overwriting `toString()` in the `MapTile` class?  Or do you mean have I tried calling the (default) toString() somewhere in my code and examining its value?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The underlying problem was that I'm an idiot.  The specific expression of this in this particular case was that I forgot that subclasses couldn't inherit private methods.  As such, the `assignImage` call wasn't being made and the image wasn't being set up.

Sorry for wasting the time of anyone who looked at this.  I feel quite embarrassed.